# How to protect my PayPal IPN handler in Joomla?

Tags: joomla, paypal, e-commerce, paypal-ipn

I'm developing small website which sells digital goods using Joomla. On my website, after confirming the customer's payment, we have to calculate some private information for him.
Hence, we have to prevent someone who didn't pay from visiting our PayPal IPN handler.
Now I have a nice IPN handler code for Joomla, which was written by [Mr. Oleksandr Balyuk](http://www.boolcast.com/joomla/development/joomla-custom-paypal-ipn).
I think, using this code, I can describe my calculation process in Joomla.
But I've one question.

How can I prevent someone who didn't pay from browsing my IPN handler?

Answer (score 0):

PayPal gives you the ability to confirm that an IPN came from them (As opposed to a spoofed IPN from a malicious user).

You simply need to post the entire contents of the received IPN back to PayPal, and you will receive a response that says **VERIFIED** if the IPN is authentic, or **INVALID** if even one character is different.

Check out page 16-17 of the IPN guide for more info:

https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/IPNGuide.pdf